# How to create two indexes for the same column that is both a primary and a foreign key?

Tags: oracle, indexing, plsql

From what I have been told and read online, I need to create an index for a foreign key even if this exact column already has an index as a primary key. But how to do that? If I simply use this

`create index document_fk_i on document(id);`

Won't it simply create a second identical index to the first one? (the first one was created automatically by Oracle)

Comment: The column is indexed because it's a primary key. A foreign key can use that same index to avoid locking issues. So who told you / where did you read this guff?

Answer (score 0):

You can't index the same column twice. If there's an index on `document.id` column because it is a primary key, then you don't (and can't) create another index which would be used for that column's "foreign key constraint" role.

Master table:

```
SQL> create table test_a (id number primary key);

Table created.
```

Detail table: `ID` is a primary key and Oracle will create an index:

```
SQL> create table test_b (id number primary key);

Table created.
```

Create a foreign key constraint from detail to master table:

```
SQL> alter table test_b add constraint fk_ba foreign key (id)
  2  references test_a (id);

Table altered.
```

Try to create additional index on detail's `ID` column:

```
SQL> create index idxb on test_b (id);
create index idxb on test_b (id)
                             *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01408: such column list already indexed


SQL>
```

Comment: I've got to wonder "WHY".  An FK points to the PK of another table.  So if this FK column is itself the PK of the table it is in ..... then you have two tables with exactly the same PK and PK values.  Sounds to me like a flawed data model.  Why would you not just combine the columns of both tables into a single table?  Read up on 'data normalization', especially Third Normal Form. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form

Comment: What? Is it about my "example" being flawed, @EdStevens? If so - well, it is just an example whose point was to show that you can't create two indexes on the same column. I don't even think that Smk actually *wants* to create something like that - it is more a discussion than *how to solve a real life problem*.

Comment: I didn't say your example was flawed.   I should have made my comment as a response to the opening post, not your answer.  (In fact, I thought I was.  Surprised to come back and see where it was in the thread)  What I was questioning was the OP's premise of having a PK of one table also be an FK to another.  Nothing to do with any potential technique to do so.  Mea culpa for the misunderstanding.

Comment: @EdStevens - we would need this construct if we are implementing an arc in a logical data model as super-type and sub-type tables. The primary key of the sub-type tables is also a foreign key on the parent super-type table.

Comment: @EdStevens, no problem. Life is full of surprises, like a box of chocolates. You never know who you are replying to :) Just kidding.